# Sharepoint 2010 designer workflow ignoring step order

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I created  designer work flow with 5 steps. Later I realized I need a step to process before the rest. I added a step to the top, but when the workflow runs, it "skips" to the original first step.

Before a manually recreate this workflow with it's about 100 lines, is there some way to make it follow the order in designer?

Likewise is there anyway to copy steps or lines?

It's extremely frustrating trying to accomplish anything with such a limited tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with sharepoint designer cache. It wasn't just skipping the first step, it was ignoring any additional changes.

see here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/03/27/tip-clearing-the-spd-workflow-assembly-cache.aspx

Also, I hate Sharepoint.